# Импорт модуля из другого каталога

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как импортировать модуль, если он расположен в другом каталоге?

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread434799.html

Comment: В одном пакете модули или независимые (верхнего уровня модули)?

Answer (score 1):

Если эта директория не входит в PYTHONPATH, то предварительно придётся выполнить

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/package/modulename')
```

Comment: 1- Манипулирование `sys.path` в своих скриптах, должно рассматриваться как грязный хак, который следует использовать только если вы знаете что делаете иначе вы человека обрекаете на поиск нетривиальных ошибок,связанных с импортом модулей в Питоне. 2- сперва я бы другие средства рассмотрел: (а) если модули внутри одного пакета, то можно просто абсолютный импорт использовать  (б) если какой-то модуль часто используется, то можно setup.py простенький по шаблону создать и просто установить модуль, используя pip

Comment: (в) явно PYTHONPATH переменную окружения при запуске/для временной сессии  указывать, если лень setup.py писать.